# CSS Border not showing up

Tags: css

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vcXe6/9/)

I'm trying to set the first `<li>` to have a border that overlaps the neighboring element's border - this will be used to hide a section of the border when a corresponding menu item is currently selected (by displaying a white border that overlaps the dark one).

CSS:

```
.side-study-box .side-box-menu .nav-selected {
    /* Works, but I need it to overlap the black border on the right */
    border-right: 2px red inset;
    /* Does not show the border because it's hidden */
    border-right: 2px red; /* Works */
    z-index: 101;
}
```

Here's my code:

```
<div class="viewport">
    <ul>
        <li> <a class="side-box-menu-control nav-text" data-bind="css: { 'nav-selected': true }"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li> <a class="side-box-menu-control nav-picture"><i class="icon-picture"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li> <a class="side-box-menu-control nav-video"><i class="icon-facetime-video"></i></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: how is your fiddle demonstrating the problem? it doesn't seem to do or show anything (at least in chrome).

Comment: What exactly is the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this (setting border-type to `solid`):

```
.side-study-box .side-box-menu .nav-selected {
    width: 22px;
    border-right: 3px red solid;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vcXe6/10/)